# php : insert into database with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database, select, insert

actually working on **Ubuntu** (working **PHP** language),
I have a PDF file that I convert into text, then I preg_match in order to extract the data I need.

After this, I **put my data lines into a drop-down list**.

PROBLEM : I want, using Ajax (as far as I understood), to **get the selected option and save it into my database**.

I've read many topic about this issue, in vain...

Here's a piece of my code, it may be more concret !

**My PHP File :**

```
$file = fopen($fichier_txt, 'r+');

if ($file)
{
    $lines = array();
    $pattern_GC = '/N°.*\d{4}(\s?\s?[\w\s]*)(\d{5})\s?(\w+)\W+/isU';
    $fichier_txt_content = file_get_contents($fichier_txt);
    $regex_GC = preg_match_all($pattern_GC, $fichier_txt_content, $match_GC);
// Match regroupant nom/prenom + adresse
$match_un = explode(PHP_EOL, $match_GC[1][0]);
$match_nom_prenom = $match_un[2];
$match_adresse = $match_un[3];
// Match CP
$match_deux = $match_GC[2][0];
// Match ville
$match_trois = $match_GC[3][0];

$opt = array($match_nom_prenom, $match_adresse, $match_deux, $match_trois);
$i = 0;?>
<html>
        <form>
            <select name="selectBox" class="drop" id="Combobox1" onchange="saveToDatabase(this.value)">
            <?php foreach($opt as $val) {?>
                <option value="$opt[$i]"><?=$val?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </form>
</html>
```

**My formulaire_2_test.php file :**

```
<?php
    // Database connection to save form lines (PDO)
            try
            {
                $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=autofill_data', 'root', 'password');
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
            }

        // Get selected option and save into database
            $selectedOpt = $_POST['selected'];
            //exit($selectedOpt); --> I put this line in comments since I don't use it everytime.


            $req = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO data_lines(idDistributeur, numLigne, libelle) VALUES(1, 2, :selectedOpt)");
            $req->bindParam(':selectedOpt', $selectedOpt);
            $req->execute($selectedOpt);
            $data = $req->fetchAll();
        }

    ?>
```

And now here is my Ajax script (i'm new in JS and I know some enormeous mistakes may pop in front of you, sorry about that, and about my french naming...)

**Ajax :** (located in my php file)

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        height:120px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
</style>

<script>

    function saveToDatabase(selectedValue)
    {
        var select = selectedValue;
        select = $(this).serialize();
        $('#Combobox1').on("change", function ()
        {
            // POST to php script
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'formulaire_2_test.php',
                data:{selected:this.value}
            }).then(function(data){alert(data)});
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        saveToDatabase();
    });

</script>
```

I tested my PDO connection with rough values, and it does work, but I wonder **how I could pass my php variable into it** (I'm not sure about using $_POST to retrieve this data since I don't refresh any page...)
I also tried with INSERT into table VALUES(:name, 2, 3) but it didn't work either...
Am I heading in the right direction ? 
How would you consider doing this ?

PS : My next step after this would be to remove the selected option from the following dropdown lists (in order to save the user some precious minutes as he fills a subscription form).

EDIT Nov 24th : I need my "Fais ton choix" option to appear on my dropdown as a default value, but not in the list options : [image: autofill]

My last issue : I want to remove the selected option of the dropdown, so it won't appear in another following dropdown. 
Here's the code I tried (doesn't work) :

```
function removeSelected(value)
        {
                $('.drop').change('select', function ()
                {
                    // Definition des variables
                    var value = this.value;
                    var id = this.id;
                    //  We del selects with a != id containing options with the same value of the selected one.
                    $("select:not(#" + id + ") option[value='" + value + "']").hide()
                });
        }
```

I also tried with .remove() instead of .hide() without success !

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Stelio Kontos.

Comment: I'd like to add that I tested my code on Firefox Consol, I can see my XHR request as I select an option, but it doesn't save into database...

Comment: You can use ```$_POST```. Ajax is just an HTTP request performed by javascript, rather than the browser window. Instead of doing ```data: 'selected=' + select```, just do ```data: {selected: select}```. Then your selected option will be available at ```$_POST['selected']```

Comment: Thanks, on my way for this ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the PHP code that follows this comment: `// Database connection to save form lines (PDO)` into a different file. From your jQuery ajax function, set the `url` to this new PHP file. Also change `data: 'selected=' + select` to `data: {selected: select}`.

Now in your PHP file (the new one) set `$selectedOpt = $_POST['selected'];`.

The last bit of your PHP code should look this this:

```
$req = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO data_lines(idDistributeur, numLigne, libelle) VALUES(1, 2, :selectedOpt)");
$req->bindParam(':selectedOpt', $selectedOpt);
$req->execute();
```

Edit: javascript fixes

Your JS should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Combobox1').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'save-selection.php',
            data: {
                // this is a reference to the select box, which means
                // this.value is the value of the select box
                selected: this.value
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Regarding your updated requirement, you can just add `$(this).children(':selected').remove();` under your ajax call. No need for another `change` listener. However, when a user selected an option, it will instantly remove it so the select box will only ever show the first option. Try it and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly send information from Javascript to PHP. You have to use some REST API or some HTTP webservice that manages HTTP request and then insert into your database.

You can program a REST API [like this](https://github.com/marcj/php-rest-service) and then simply use **$_POST['selected']** to retrieve the parameter of the POST request you did with JQuery.

Also, I recommend you to use [minAjax](http://flouthoc.github.io/minAjax.js/)

Comment: You can invoke a new XMLHttpRequest in javascript to a PHP script. No REST API necessary.

Comment: @BenGuest True, but the REST API is a good tool and easy to master. I do it that way.

Comment: They are a very useful tool, maybe a little overkill for this particular problem though?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer freinn.
It seems a little heavy for me, I only have a week left to get this working, hence I was wondering if there was a way to do it without a REST API.

Regarding minAjax, is there a difference from the ajax library ? Or is it just lighter (=>faster to run) ?

Comment: The recommendation of minAjax is confusing, there is nothing wrong with using jQuery ajax.

Comment: I'm really trying not to get into overkill, since time is running out :( !
I'm gonna have a look to this XHR invoke anyway, hope it's easy to use !

I'll keep you in touch ASAP.

Comment: @StelioKontos I recommended minAjax because is easier to use and has no restrictions (less error-prone). Is just include the .js file and invoke the minAjax function. You can get this done today. Just do the easiest form Ben Guest told here on the comments. Do a POST to a URL where you will have your PHP script that simply get the $_POST array parameters and interacts with the DB.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna look into this more seriously as I already attempted it yesterday...! Any code suggestion would be helpful as I'm not sure how to perform this.

var selectedOpt = $_POST['name_of_select']; 
And then I $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'my_file.php', data:{selected:selectedOpt });

Should it look like this ?

Comment: @StelioKontos yes, but don't forget that PHP has not *var*, simply use $selectedOpt = $_POST['name_of_select'];